# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto

Ответ с сервера :

```
{
  "timestamp": 1519067128827,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/CarService"
}
```

POST звпрос :

```
{
  "address": "address1"
}
```

Controller:

```
package by.bsuir.controllers;

import by.bsuir.dto.CarServiceDTO;
import by.bsuir.services.api.CarServService;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/CarService")
public class CarServiceController {

  private final CarServService carServService;

  @Autowired
  public CarServiceController(CarServService carServService) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("CarServiceControllerConstructor");
    }
    this.carServService = carServService;
  }

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<CarServiceDTO> addCarService(@RequestBody CarServiceDTO CarServiceDTO) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("createCarService(" + CarServiceDTO + ")");
    }
    CarServiceDTO dto = carServService.save(CarServiceDTO);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<CarServiceDTO>> getAllCarServices() {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("getAllCarServices()");
    }
    List<CarServiceDTO> CarServices = carServService.findAll();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(CarServices)) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(CarServices, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<CarServiceDTO> getCarServiceById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("getCarServiceById(" + id + ")");
    }
    CarServiceDTO CarServiceDTO = carServService.findById(id);
    if (CarServiceDTO != null) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(CarServiceDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
  }

  @PutMapping
  public ResponseEntity<CarServiceDTO> updateCarService(@RequestBody CarServiceDTO CarServiceDTO) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("updateCarService(" + CarServiceDTO + ")");
    }
    CarServiceDTO dto = carServService.update(CarServiceDTO);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity deleteCarService(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("deleteCarService(" + id + ")");
    }
    carServService.deleteById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Dto:

```
package by.bsuir.dto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarServiceDTO extends BaseDTO {

  private String address;
  private Map<SparePartDTO, Integer> sparePartsCount;
  private List<MasterDTO> masters = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

У аннотации `PostMapping` есть 2 параметра `consumes` и `produces`.

- `consumes` - в каком виде вы будете принимать информацию
- `produces` - в каком виде вы будете отдавать информацию

В вашем случае надо указать `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8`

Такие же параметры есть и у других аннотация маппинга.

Comment: Не помогло, подозреваю что все дело в :  private Map<SparePartDTO, Integer> sparePartsCount; т.к. другие запросы post работают

Comment: Когда убрал из DTO :  private Map<SparePartDTO, Integer> sparePartsCount; Всё нормально отработало подскажите , что с этим делать??